# Server distribution for high performance

Tags: networking, server-side, sockets, tcp

I've developed a Socket Application on top of TCP in .NET C#, which allows many clients to send files from one another via a VPS I'm using. Most file transfers will occur between people in the same region, say, even in the same neighborhood.

So, If 300 clients are connected, some of them will be connected from say Europe, others from, say the USA etc... Those who are connected from Europe will never try to send files to those in the USA.

What matters to me the most is scalability (hopefully, I will have thousands of users connecting simultaneously), and low latency (responsiveness) when it comes to upload/download transfer rates.

Something tells me, that if I want the files (up to 2MB) to be transferred quickly between my clients, I should get a VPS in Europe, USA, Asia etc. In this way, users will get higher transfer rates, and in case one of the server fails, they will be able to use the the other one(s). Besides, I should have a separate database for user info/statistics to which all of the servers connect when needed.

My question is, what is the common practice for such usage and requirements? Any kind of clue/terminology I should start to get familiar with will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Whatever your solution, consider that geographical proximity and IP connection speed are not correlated. I may have a higher speed with someone on the other side of the world than with my next-door neighbour, depending on the interlink speeds of the respective ISP's.

Comment: You mean something like dropbox or wetransfer?

Comment: You said high performance, but what are your performance requirements?

Comment: @BrianSnow High performance for me, high transfer rate and the ability to serve many clients.

Comment: @LucFranken No not really. More like a torrent, only you choose exactly who you are sending the file to.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau isn't the principle of CDN's based on the fact that the farther away the server, the slower the data rate? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Daniel: A torrent is also peer-to-peer. You share a small file with meta data and the actual data is sent peer-to-peer. So it is not really clear now. Do you want to send files (on behalf of your users) from one of your servers to clients? Of do you want to let users send files directly from their own system to another client?

Comment: @LucFranken The final goal is client-client file transfer. At the moment the clients connect to a server, and choose who they want to send the file to. Then they send the file to the other side *via the server*, and not directly

Comment: @Daniel: No, it is more based on the principle that the more networks you have to navigate through, the slower the data rate. There are only a limited number of interlinks between the various networks and those can become bottlenecks for the data rate.By limiting the number of interlinks the data has to navigate, you can increase the data rate. You could call this "internet proximity" (as opposed to geographical proximity)

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Thanks for that. In your opinion, is there a way for me to implement something like CDNs only for a socket application? I mean, a way for clients to connect to the "internet-closest" servers?

Comment: @Daniel: Sure, you can still use a pool of geographically distributed servers (or something similar). You just can't presume that the geographically closest server will also be the "internet closest" server, though it can be a decent first offer. Either let the user choose or do a speed test (on installation/geographical relocation).

Comment: Seems like you're trying to build your own CDN, without realizing how difficult the task actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice in such a problem would be to change your server to me only meta-server, while file transfer would be peer-to-peer. This is for example how Skype works.

If you don't want to rewrite whole application logic, you can use CDN. Just keep in mind, that many CDNs are designed for static content. Make sure to use one, that actually works for dynamic content. Amazon's CloudFront is one example, CloudFlare CDN is another. In this case client both upload and download would go to respective CDN endpoints (the closest ones to their internet location), then through internal CDN provider's network to your server. Combined with auto-scalable server you'll achieve practically unlimited scalability. However that will be rather expensive.

Comment: Let's Assume I don't wish to rewrite my whole network application, and use TCP sockets. Is there a way to distribute the servers such that the file transfer rate will increase?